# F# pattern matching: how "as" is interpreted when used incorrectly with constructor?

Tags: f#

I have a discriminated union with a choice that has another du as its type as follows:

```
type DunionSubset =
    | X
    | Y
type Dunion =
    | A
    | B
    | C of DunionSubset
```

I want to produce a mapping to a list of strings for `Dunion` type, which naturally extends to `C` and therefore `DunionSubset`

When I incorrectly use as to assign an alias to constructor as follows:

```
let MappingsOfC = function
    | X -> ["x"]
    | Y -> ["y"]

let StringMappings = function
    | A -> ["a";"A"]
    | B -> []
    | C  as c -> (MappingsOfC c)
```

the compiler gives me:

```
[FS0019] This constructor is applied to 0 argument(s) but expects 1
```

How exactly is my incorrect use of as above leading to this compiler error? Interestingly, the location of the compiler error is that of  `C`, not my use of `c` in `MappingsOfC c` though Rider ide underlines `c` and provides a different error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C as c` matches the function argument against the pattern `C` and also binds it to `c`. So it's the same as:

```
let StringMappings c = match c with
    | A -> ["a";"A"]
    | B -> []
    | C -> (MappingsOfC c)
```

except that this will make `c` visible in all branches whereas the version with `as` only makes `c` visible in the branch that has the `as` pattern (naturally).

You get an error because `C` takes an argument, but you're trying to use it without one. If you wrote `| A as a ->`, `| B as b ->` and/or `| C _ as c`, that would work fine.

Comment: thanks, especially for explaining the form with explicit match.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the left part of `->` (before the `as` and `when` keywords, if provided) in a matching branch is a **pattern**. And pattern must be valid - depending on the type of the value provided right after the `match` keyword.

Here compiler will understand that you are wanting to match a `Dunion` value because it sees the patterns `A` and `B` (which are all valid) first.

Now you can see that `C` is an invalid pattern for `Dunion`. The valid pattern here must be: `C something`

If you don’t care about `something` (don’t need to use it), still, you must provide a wildcard `_` to make the pattern valid: `C _`

But in your example, I’m pretty sure that you do care, so the code should be like this:

```
| C c -> MappingsOfC c
```